# What are droid brains made of?

Tags: star-wars, robots, technology, artificial-intelligence

Has a source ever confirmed what droid brains are made of?

Since Artificial Intelligence is likely extremely complex and energy consuming, I have my doubts that it's made of silicon, but I'd like to know, one way or the other.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  A quick google suggests that not all droids use verbobrains.  Are you asking specifically about verbobrains (as used by, for example, protocol droids) or about droid brains in general?

Comment: Sorry droid brains in general. I thought they were all called Verbobrains.

Comment: Snips and snails and puppy-dog tails

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Silicon

Mace Windu encounters an artifically intelligent satellite in the novel *[Shatterpoint](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Shatterpoint_(novel))*. Its droid brain is composed of silicon.

> One fracture terminated at an orbiting satellite that whizzed across
> the face of the planet at almost twenty-eight thousand kilometers per
> hour, and **through the fracture he could feel a silicon brain make an
> electronic connection.**

The [New Essential Guide to Characters](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_New_Essential_Guide_to_Characters) describes 4-Lom (a serving droid-turned robot bounty hunter) as having "*silicon dreams*"

> Zuckuss repaired his partner. But due to some quirk in his rebuilt
> processors, or simply the sting of failure, 4-LOM was never the same
> again. His earlier bout of Rebel idealism vanished **like a silicon
> dream.**

Comment: This reminds me of the classic Eurythmics song: "Silicon Dreams Are Made Of This" :D

Comment: @HansOlo - The lack of a canon reference is a thorn in my side. But I expect I'll be able to find one when tomorrow comes :-)